# Realm and Swift - parameters to pass for the model to be updated

Tags: swift, database, model, realm

In the beginning of the project, Realm is great and easy to work and the project is getting complicated so I need to figure out how to decouple the realm layer and uiviewcontroller.

There is some awkwardness by writing a realm object with parameters. I would like to have object updated with the parameter then pass to the realm database to update object in (table?). Initially, I have a function to write a realm object by -

```
func createOrUpdateNote(note : Note, body : String, textSize : Float, toggleColor : Int) {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        do {
            try realm.write {
                if note.id == -1 {
                    note.id = NoteManager.createNotePrimaryId()
                }
                note.body = body
                note.textSize = textSize
                note.toggleColor = toggleColor
                realm.add(note, update: true)
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

I would like to have like this function. Hope it clears up my question here.

```
func createOrUpdateNote(note : Note) {
            let realm = try! Realm()
            do {
                try realm.write {
                    realm.add(note, update: true)
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

Now I have another viewcontroller to update the object with their preference of using language below.

```
func createOrUpdateNote(note : Note, language : String) {
            let realm = try! Realm()
            do {
                try realm.write {
                    if note.id == -1 {
                        note.id = NoteManager.createNotePrimaryId()
                    }
                    note.language = language
                    realm.add(note, update: true)
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

There will be two similar functions (dup functions) in database layer and that will not work well when the project is getting more features so I'm stepping back to see if I can redesign the create or update the object approach.

I googled and there are several solutions like making UI object and copy the ui values over to the realm objects each time I do CRUD, create object with internal realm object (1 to 1 mapping), or I'm thinking about partial update but not sure how can I approach this situation. Ideally, I would prefer only object to carry over to be updated. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? That code works for creating or updating a Realm object so it's unclear what's not working.

Comment: the issue is the design pattern of realm. I'm not able to update the realm object with some variable without the write block. So I need to pass the parameters from the UI along to the database manager class. Is there a way to update the object then update the object in database? I'm thinking to have a model controller and update the realm object with parameters there.

Comment: Can you provide an example of when you would want to update an objects variable a not have it written to Realm? It appears you have a note object with three properties: body, textSize and color. If a user opens a note for example, and changes the body, the next step is to save it, which would be done within a write. Where in the process would a var need to be updated but not written? Our app has a specific use case for this so I may have an answer but want to make sure the question is clear first.

Comment: I think I'm not clear on this question.  I have a ViewController and NoteManager. The NoteManager has functions to create, delete, update, get notes. I would like to keep only one update function instead of several "update" functions for the parameters. This violates duplicate code rule but realm doesn't let us update the note beforehand then update the note in realm. I'm wondering if there is any other way. The question is more of design pattern? Thank you for reading/your input.

Comment: It's still very unclear. There is no *duplicate code rule* - you can duplicate code in whatever fashion you like. It's just more efficient to maintain a smaller code base which also makes it more maintainable. We have a notes app we use internally. When a user selects a note, it opens in a sheet (this is macOS desktop) where they can edit, and then when they click OK, the note is either added or updated. All of that is done through one write function and one block of code. There's not much too it really so it's unclear why you would have several update functions; it can all be done in one.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I have update note function with parameters - func createOrUpdateNote(note : Note, body : String, textSize : Float, toggleColor : Int) in NoteManager which is the realm transactions are. I have a new update function - func updateFontStyle(note : Note, fontStyle : FontStyle). This function is for note settings. Those functions are calling realm and update the note with parameters. I wanted to make it more efficient by getting only a parameter with a single realm object (note).  That is what I want to know if there is any other way to make it efficient. It's about reusability

Comment: The issue is still unclear to me. Storing a Note object in realm persists that object - meaning it's saved (to disk/cloud etc). If a change is made to that Note object, the assumption is you want to save that change; and that would be done within a write closure. In what use case would you want to update an object and not save the change? In other words, you are correct in stating you cannot *update an existing persisted Realm object without a write block*. But why would you? What's the problem with saving those changes?

Comment: I have android app which has a sqllite and I just store the values (parameters) in the note object and then update the record with the note object.The note manager in android app has only a single update function.With realm in ios app, I created several update functions with note, and different parameters. Maybe this link clears up what issue I'm facing - https://dev.to/jordanosterberg/-realm-database-guide---building-a-note-app-in-swift-for-ios-4dbl.I'm going with model controller approach with several update functions but organized in their own model controller where I can prototype quickly.

Comment: The problem is that I have to track all of those update functions. I wasn't sure if that is a good approach.

Comment: That link is an example of one method of saving a Realm object. It's not clear what you mean by *all of those update functions* as there is only one. With SQLite you essentially get a reference to your database, then `database.insert(xxxx)` and then close. Realm is very similar in that you get a Realm reference, call the write function and update your object within the write (e.g. insert) closure. If you notice in your question, *all* of the functions contain this `realm.add(note, update: true)` and that one line does it all. Update whatever fields you want, and then call the .add function.

Comment: You are right. I just wasn't accustomed to seeing several write blocks around in app. Thank you for your patience with me. Cheers

Comment: I threw in an answer that kind of summarized all of this. There's no one solution so I included a couple of options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an existing (managed) Realm object, its properties can only be modified within a write block. However, ANY of it's properties can be modified and you really only need one block 'style' to do it.

So for example, if we have a Note Realm object

```
Note: Object {
   @objc dynamic var body = ""
   @objc dynamic var textSize = 12
   @objc dynamic var language = "English"
}
```

any time we have access to that Note, we can modify it's properties within a write closure. Let's say a user is editing an existing note and changes the body, then clicks Save.

```
let realm = try Realm()

try! realm.write {
     myNote.body = updatedBodyText
     realm.add(myNote, update: true)
}
```

or they change the text size

```
let realm = try Realm()

try! realm.write {
     myNote.textSize = updatedTextSize
     realm.add(myNote, update: true)
}
```

Notice that those blocks are identical, other than which property is updated. The key is to hang on to a reference to the note when loaded, so you can then modify it's properties in a write block when saving.

There's no problem having multiple write blocks depending on what property you're saving. It really depends on your use case but that's common practice.

Generically speaking it could also be rolled into one function, something like this:

```
func saveMyNote(myNote: NoteClass, updatedData: String, fieldType: NoteFieldTypes) {

   try! realm.write {
      switch fieldType:
      case .body:
         myNote.body = updatedData
      case .language:
         myNote.language = updatedData
      etc etc

      realm.add(myNote, update: true)
}
```

You could also extend the class or a variety of other solutions. In general the write code is so small I would just use it wherever you need to update an objects fields.

Comment: that's the answer what I'm looking for, thank you! I didn't think about the enums - fieldType: NoteFieldTypes... a cool way to do that.